# Image Not Displaying when the path is Temp Folder in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the content of Image in `byteArray` format from the database and displaying it in the Content image tag in ASP.NET.The problem is that when I save the image file in a specific location in my working folder and display the image,it is working fine.But if I try to save the image in a temporary folder and pass the temporary folder URL to image tag it doesn't display the image.

**code**:

```
   Bitmap bi = new Bitmap(byteArrayToImage(FileUpload1.FileBytes));

 //This code working fine

 string path = Server.MapPath("Images/") + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
         bi.Save(path , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "Images/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;



//This code didn't displaying the image.

         bi.Save(Path.GetTempPath() + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Image1.ImageUrl = Path.GetTempPath() + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

what is the problem with the tempFolder here?.I am using the Windows7 OS.Here i am using the temparory folder for automatically deleting the created images from the folder.

Thank you

Comment: Does it throw an error? If it does could we have it? If it doesn't, what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug and check if the ImageUrl is correct

Comment: Here images path getting the same.

Comment: Hey try this...
string path = Server.MapPath("Images/") + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; replace it with this.... string path = "Images/"+ FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;